# Some icons from Font Awesome

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I'm having problem with font awesome recently. I'm using Angular 10 with [Angular MDC](https://trimox.github.io/angular-mdc-web/#/angular-mdc-web/getting-started) and font awesome. Problem is that some icons just doesn't work.

First I have instaled font awesome.

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Then, I have included it in the `angular.json` file.

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/@fontawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
],
```

Registed font class alias to Icon Registry.

```
export class AppModule {
    constructor(iconRegistry: MdcIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        iconRegistry.registerFontClassAlias('fontawesome', 'fa');
    }
}
```

And then I have used the mdc-icon component to display icons. Like this:

```
<mdc-icon fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-..."></mdc-icon>
```

It worked until, I tried to use Discord icon, when I use this icon it behaves as if the icon doesn't exist. I have looked into the lib. files and I have found svg file of this icon so I would like to know why this is and how to fix this. Thanks.